# how to install windows 8.1 under virtualbox in ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

please i need the directions on how to install the windows on the ubuntu terminal using the virtualbox app. Or how to install windows 8.1 alongside the ubuntu 14.04, and how to update the ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was installing windows after installing Ubuntu. Problem is that you can't boot Ubuntu anymore after that, but you can fix this using boot repair.

Ubuntu and many other Linux distributions use the GRUB2 boot loader. If GRUB2 breaks — for example, if you install Windows after installing Ubuntu or overwrite your MBR — you won’t be able to boot into Ubuntu.

You can easily restore GRUB2 from a Ubuntu live CD or USB drive. This process is different from restoring the legacy GRUB boot loader on older Linux distributions.

Graphical Method – Boot Repair
Boot Repair is a graphical tool that can repair GRUB2 with a single click. This is the ideal solution to boot problems for most users.

If you have the media you installed Ubuntu from, insert it into your computer and restart. If you don’t, download a Ubuntu live CD and burn it to a disc or install it on a USB flash drive. You can also download a [dedicated Boot Repair live CD.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

After booting into the live Ubuntu environment, open a terminal from the Dash and run the following commands to install Boot Repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

The Boot Repair window will appear after you run the boot-repair command. After it scans your system, click the Recommended repair button to repair GRUB2 with a single click.

[image]
The Boot Repair window will appear after you run the boot-repair command. After it scans your system, click the Recommended repair button to repair GRUB2 with a single click.

[image]

You can also click the Advanced options header to customize GRUB2’s options without learning its command-line syntax.

[image]

Restart your computer after using the Boot Repair tool. Ubuntu should boot up normally.

Source:
http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/